# Mod Rewrite rewrite URL weird behavior, keeps adding query string to displayed URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a beginner.

### What I want

1. the request URL `.../activity/1415/abcdefgh/` to be rewritten to `.../activity/gallery.php?k=abcdefgh`
2. but still display the URL to the visitor as `.../activity/1415/abcdefgh/`.

But when I try, the URL `.../activity/1415/abcdefgh/` turned to `.../activity/1415/abcdefgh/?k=abcdefgh`.

The page displays fine, but I want to **hide the query**.

---

### Basically what happened

1. Link says: `http://localhost/activity/1516/iolfpqwx`
2. Clicked link
3. Address bar says: `http://localhost/activity/1516/iolfpqwx/?key=iolfpqwx`, which I don't want.

---

### My **entire** `.htaccess` in the `activity/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(\w{8,})(?:/([\w\s]+)?)?$ gallery.php?key=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

---

### My Specs:

- XAMPP on Windows with Apache

---

### What I know

- I have not setup any redirect rules on my testing server, so I don't believe I have any `[R]` flags.
- I have a similar `.htaccess` in an adjacent directory with the code `RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/*$ index.php?p=settings&s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` and it didn't show me query strings.

I've Googled my issue, but cannot find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Your current rewrite rule should be correct. Did you previously have a `[R]` flag in there? I ask because browsers often aggressively cache redirects and you may be seeing a stale redirect.  Do you get the same behavior if you try it in a different browser or private/icognito window?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I made a new path to test and the problem still exist. Maybe I shouldn't use mod_rewrite for this?